# invalidate() the Rect to call onDraw() within time interval

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a class called **GraphView.java** and a activity called **MainActivity.java.**  I want to run a timer  of 40 miliseconds on MainActivity.java to control invalidate();  on GraphView.java  means it should call onDraw() within 40 milisecond.

how this one is possible ?

I have tried with postinvalidate()  it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: can you shows us what you have done?

Comment: No I havn,t used the timer.  I want to use Hanlder.postdelayed()  how this is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.invalidate;
            }
         });
     } 
}, 40);
```

Comment: dont use any Timer, it creates a new Thread under the hood, use Handler instead

Comment: @pskink Timer will be executed only after the interval is elapsed, so doesnt create performance issues I guess. I am not very sure though, please can you reason out why its not suitable?

Comment: because you create a new Thread and more important: every 40 ms you create a new Runnable

Comment: @pskink This won't be repeated every 40ms. I have tested it, it gets executed only once after 40ms.

Comment: ok, my fault, it will be run only once, but still its a bad idea to use a Timer when you can sumply call Handler.postDelayed

Comment: Yes it is correct Handler.postDelayed is better idea rather timer as and simpler

Comment: @Yogesh Tatwal But there is a problem with Handler.postDelayed()  If i will my plotfuntion within 40 milisecond . Total time it will take  ie:  Time of Execution of that function + 40 milisecond  Means after executing that function it will wait for 40 miliseconds more .That I don't want . Hope you have understood my problem

Comment: @user1844130 Please give some code. Why are you getting a TimeOutException? Unless you provide some code how can we understand why and when you are calling your plotFunction() which gives exception